# How can I merge more arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have 3 or more array :

```
 var array1 = [a,b,c];
 var array2 = [c,d];
 var array3 = [e,f];
```

Want to get 1 merged array with the result like this one:

```
result = [ace, acf, ade, adf, bce, bdf, bde, bdf, cce, ccf, cde, cdf]
```

How can I do it? Please note: array input will not limit.

Comment: It seems your looking for all combinations, not a "merge".

Comment: I agree, that's not `.concat()` you're looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach with a combination algorithm.

```js
function combine(array) {
    function c(part, index) {
        array[index].forEach(function (a) {
            var p = part.concat([a]);
            if (p.length === array.length) {
                r.push(p.join(''));
                return;
            }
            c(p, index + 1);
        });
    }

    var r = [];

    c([], 0);
    return r;
}

console.log(combine([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]));
console.log(combine([['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e'], ['f', 'g'], ['h', 'i', 'j']]));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try using for loop** [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z7hmx88j/)

```js
var array1 = ["a", "b", "c"];
var array2 = ["c", "d"];
var array3 = ["e", "f"];
var result = [], pushresult = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
    for (var k = 0; k < array3.length; k++) {
      pushresult = array1[i] + array2[j] + array3[k];
      result.push(pushresult);
    }
  }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why post elsewhere when you can make your code a runnable snippet here?

Comment: Ya. But, I don't know how to do it. :(

Comment: @priya_singh for you reference [Format code blocks](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: Thank for your help. But if i have 4, 5 or 100 arrays like that, i have to use 100 time loop? :((. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are trying to get the ***Cartesian product*** from multiple arrays(sets).
Consider the following ES6 solution using `Array.concat`, `Array.reduce` and `Array.map` functions:

```js
const flatten = (arr) => [].concat.apply([], arr);
const product = (...sets) =>
    sets.reduce((acc, set) =>
            flatten(acc.map(x => set.map(y => [ ...x, y ]))),
    [[]]);

var array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    array2 = ['c','d'],
    array3 = ['e','f'];

result = product(array1, array2, array3);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: Up-voting this for identifying catesian product.

Answer (score 0):

```
if you number of array is fixed (not array element) then you can use

<script>
var array1 = ["a","b","c"];
var array2 = ["c","d"];
var array3 = ["e","f"];
var d=[];
for(i in array1){
    for (j in array2){
        for(k in array3){
        d.push(array1[i]+array2[j]+array3[k]);  
        }
    }
}
alert(d);
</script>
```

Comment: `for..in` is more suited for looping over objects

Answer (score 0):

The List applicative and monad can achieve this with ease

```js
// Array Applicative  
Array.prototype.ap = function ( ...args )
  {
    const loop = ( acc , [ x , ...xs ] ) =>
      x === undefined
        ? [ this [ 0 ] ( ...acc ) ]
        : x.chain ( a =>
            loop ( acc.concat ( [ a ] ) , xs ) )
    return loop ( [] , args )
  }
 
// Array Monad
Array.prototype.chain = function chain (f)
  {
    return this.reduce ( ( acc , x ) =>
      acc.concat ( f (x) ), [] )
  }

// the hard work is already done
const combinations = ( ...xxs ) =>
  [ ( ...xs ) => xs ] .ap ( ...xxs )

console.log ( combinations ( array1 , array2 , array3 ) )
// [ [ 'a1', 'a2', 'a3' ],
//   [ 'a1', 'a2', 'b3' ],
//   [ 'a1', 'a2', 'c3' ],
//   [ 'a1', 'b2', 'a3' ],
//   [ 'a1', 'b2', 'b3' ],
//   [ 'a1', 'b2', 'c3' ],
//   [ 'b1', 'a2', 'a3' ],
//   [ 'b1', 'a2', 'b3' ],
//   [ 'b1', 'a2', 'c3' ],
//   [ 'b1', 'b2', 'a3' ],
//   [ 'b1', 'b2', 'b3' ],
//   [ 'b1', 'b2', 'c3' ],
//   [ 'c1', 'a2', 'a3' ],
//   [ 'c1', 'a2', 'b3' ],
//   [ 'c1', 'a2', 'c3' ],
//   [ 'c1', 'b2', 'a3' ],
//   [ 'c1', 'b2', 'b3' ],
//   [ 'c1', 'b2', 'c3' ],
//   [ 'd1', 'a2', 'a3' ],
//   [ 'd1', 'a2', 'b3' ],
//   [ 'd1', 'a2', 'c3' ],
//   [ 'd1', 'b2', 'a3' ],
//   [ 'd1', 'b2', 'b3' ],
//   [ 'd1', 'b2', 'c3' ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need an `Array.prototype.cartesian()` for indefinite number of arrays. It can be done as follows;

```js
Array.prototype.cartesian = function(...a){
  return a.length ? this.reduce((p,c) => (p.push(...a[0].cartesian(...a.slice(1)).map(e => a.length > 1 ? [c,...e] : [c,e])),p),[])
                  : this;
};

var arr1 = ["a","b","c"],
    arr2 = ["c","d"],
    arr3 = ["e","f"],
  result = arr1.cartesian(arr2,arr3);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```